# How to modify src attribute in image to make many cards VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I want to have many card from my component and I want to change the src attribute on every image. Please help me to do it. Thankyou :D

```html
<!---THIS IS MY PAGE FILE---->

<template>
  <div>
      <class-list :src="image1"></class-list>
      <class-list :src="image2"></class-list>
      <class-list :src="image3"></class-list>
      <class-list :src="image4"></class-list>
  </div>
</template>


<!---THIS IS MY COMPONENT FILE---->

<template>
  <div>
        <a-card hoverable style="width: 240px">
            <img
                slot="cover"
                alt="example"
                :src="image"
                />
                <a-card-meta title="Europe Street beat">
                <template slot="description">
                    www.instagram.com
                </template>
            </a-card-meta>
        </a-card>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You should have the prop passed down to the component, then use it in the template of the component. Did you defined `image` in your component? Also, what do you expect with `slot="cover"`? Then in your page, you could have an URL linked to let's say `image4`.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of code should solve your use-case, here is a [SFC link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

`page`

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="image in images">
    <card :image="image"></card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Card from './Card.vue'
export default {
  components: { Card },
  data() {
    return {
      images: ['https://images.pexels.com/photos/5044497/pexels-photo-5044497.jpeg', 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/9365604/pexels-photo-9365604.jpeg', 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/10392192/pexels-photo-10392192.jpeg']
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`Card.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img slot="cover" alt="example" :src="image" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['image']
}
</script>

<style scoped>
img { 
  width: 200px;
}
</style>
```

Here is the end result

[image]